# How can I know what pixel density version of an image Android is using?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-image, android-screen-support

I am absolutly new in Android development and I am developing my first app.

I have the following doubts related how to correctly handle different version of images having different pixel density:

Using this online tool: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html I have created the **mdpi**, **hdpi** **xhdpi**, **xxhdpi** and **xxxhdpi** version of my images, then I have created this structure into the **/res/** directory of my project:

[image]

Then I use these immage in this way into my layout definition:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/carbonara" />
```

What it exactly means? Android automatically choose the correct version basing on the screen of the used device?

Into the Android Studio activity preview I see the immage correctly showed but how can I check that the immage showed is correct one for the chosen device?

For example, into Android Studio preview, I select **Nexus 4** as device, can I see what image is using for this device?

I also use these image into the Java code of my app, for example I do something like this:

```
imgSlideView.setImageResource(R.drawable.amatriciana);
```

By **R.drawable.amatriciana** I think that Android automaticall retrieve the version suitable with the used device screen. Can I obtain some information about what exactly version is loading?

Comment: Yes, it is *supposed* to choose and display an appropriate image, but let me warn you: *don't* rely on an "Android Studio preview!"  You need to get out there and buy *devices,* especially old ones. If there's a used-CD store in your town, or a Goodwill store, or any other peddlers of "old but gently-used electronics," become their customer.  Notice what devices are sold in grocery stores:  a **lot** of people buy their devices there. The makers of many Android-compatible devices took many "cost-saving* shortcuts, and "video" is a "costly" component. ... **O_o** ...

Answer (score 1):

Android uses qualifiers such as mdpi, land (landscape), fr, etc. to display an activity or any layout based component and handle ressources correctly.

So, an xml file stored in *land-large* folder will be inflated only when the device has a large screen size, mostly for tablets, and a landscape orientation.

The same qualifiers are used to handle string ressources in different languages.

For drawables case, Android will only load ressources matching the device configurations.

Answer (score 1):

**What it exactly means? Android automatically choose the correct version basing on the screen of the used device?**

Exactly, android will automatically choose the most convenient size depending of the display of the device where your app is running.

**Into the Android Studio activity preview I see the immage correctly showed but how can I check that the immage showed is correct one for the chosen device?** 
The chosen image should be the same (but in different sizes/density). You will see a preview depending of the device you are using (or debugging on), but another device might see another version (a tablet will most likely see the high density image).

Those are the answers that i am certain of, you can check for some useful information here:

[Android Screen Support](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)